# data structure with fast insertion and fast lookup for {(integer, value)}

Tags: indexing, data-structures, tree

Let's say that we are receiving data in a key-value pair fashion.
A typical stream of data is

```
(205, c)
(2, a)
(1006, b)
....
```

so the key is an integer and the value is a pointer to some arbitrary data.

They are two requirements:
1) It is not known how many key-value pair will be sent, so the data-structure should grow dynamically.

2) The data structure should support fast look up.
For example, given the key 3, the key-value pair returned should be (2, a).

What data structure would be efficient for this problem?

I know how to treat the requirement individually. For (1), I can use a linked list. For (2), I can use a binary tree. But I don't see a data-structure that would provide both.

A solution in any language is ok, as long as it doesn't use some package of that language, because I'm implementing this in Fortran.

Comment: Look at hashing datastructure like map

Comment: @SMA To me 'map' is a very broad term, any specific implementation name?

Comment: Did you tried to google for map data structure?

Comment: @sma 'map data structure' gives plenty of info, thanks.